# Pyside2 QDialog Background Graphics

Tags: python, pyside2

I am working on making dropdown/popup windows for my i3bar/i3blocks setup. The idea is to have a Qt.Popup type window open when a certain i3block is clicked, which will be positioned above the i3block to look like a popup menu. I have most of this working, but would like to add partial borders to the Qt window like I have drawn on in the picture (in red):

[image: example popup with desired border in red]

Ideally the border would not go all the way around the pop up but would stop where the popup "connects" to the i3block it extends, (the battery i3block in the example). The border should however extend on the bottom to separate the popup from other i3blocks (example: the calendar block). This is not the only popup that I would like to make and others might "hang over" neighboring i3blocks more or less and possibly on both sides. The start and end location of the border brake (x and y, if needed) would be in px.

I have looked at using QGraphicsView to simply draw those lines on, but can't figure out how to get any QGraphics to work when the window is a QDialog. Is adding the graphics possible? If so, how?

Note: I don't want to use a background image, because I want the border line width to be the same regardless of the window size.

Here is the relevant code:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import * 
from PySide2.QtGui import * 
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt

class Main(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Popup)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 50, 100)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF")
        

        #omitted info widgets and layouts would go here
   
        
        layout_main = QVBoxLayout()
        #layout_main.addLayout(layout_TLP)
        #layout_main.addLayout(layout_sleepTime)

        self.setLayout(layout_main)
        self.show()




app = QApplication([])
main = Main()
main.exec_()
```

Comment: Something like `self.setStyleSheet("Main { background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; border: 1px solid red; }")`?

Comment: That is certainly an option, but ideally I would only have the border go partially across the bottom, leaving out the part directly above the i3block it is extending (in my picture the battery block), hence why I thought I would have to manually draw it. The location of the start and end points of the border-less part would be in px if that makes any difference.

Comment: then please [edit] the question, provide a more accurate and precise image, and clarify where/how the border should be drawn.

Comment: Done. Let me know if I was unclear on anything else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QGraphicsView is intended to show 2D custom graphics itemd in a *scene*, not to customize the painting of widgets. In order to achieve what you want, you need to use a [QPainter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html) created within the [`paintEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent) of the widget, which is the function that is called by *any* widget whenever they need to be displayed.

There are various functions that draw primitive graphics, like rectangles, ellipses and text; in your case you need to work with lines (since you're not drawing a full rectangle) but, since lines drawn individually are not connected, the result might not be fine if the border has a width bigger than one pixel, so you should opt for [`drawPolyline`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawPolyline).

The approach is the following:

- get the current widget rectangle, and ​subtract one pixel from the right and the bottom to get the actual painting rectangle;
- *reduce* the rectangle by *half* the width of the border that is being drawn (lines extend from their middle by half of the pen size: a horizontal line drawn at `y = 10` with a width by 2 is drawn from `y = 9` to `y = 11`);
- get the point at the right of the bottom edge, where the small line has to "stop";
- set the *pen* of the border (color and width);
- draw the polyline;

```
class Main(QWidget):
    _borderSize = 2
    _bottomWidth = 140
    # ...
    def setBorderSize(self, size):
        self._borderSize = max(1, size)
        self.update()

    def setBottomWidth(self, width):
        self._bottomWidth = max(0, width)
        self.update()

    ​def paintEvent(self, event):
        # the border width could be odd, so we must convert
        # the rectangle to QRectF which supports floating point
        # coordinates, which is also better for QPainter
        rect = QRectF(self.rect().adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1))
        half = self._borderSize / 2
        rect.adjust(half, half, -half, -half)
        bottomLeft = QPointF(rect.left(), rect.bottom() + half)
        bottomRight = QPointF(self._bottomWidth, rect.bottom())

        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHints(qp.Antialiasing)
        qp.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, self._borderSize))
        qp.drawPolyline(QPolygonF((
            bottomLeft,
            rect.topLeft(),
            rect.topRight(),
            rect.bottomRight(),
            bottomRight
        )))

app = QApplication([])
main = Main()
app.exec()
```

Note that I inherited from QWidget: since you're overriding the window flags and you're not using the window modality (there's only one window), there's no need for a QDialog, and you can just start the app's event loop which will quit as soon as the widget is closed.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I was looking for. For future reference the import statement in my example `from PySide2.QtCore import Qt` has to be changed to `from PySide2.QtCore import *`. Also, unless I am missing something, QDialog is necessary; if I change it to QWidget, the event loop never ends after the window has been closed.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind subtracting 1 from the right and bottom of the rectangle? The polyline is on the edge of the window without calling `adjusted` when I run it.